# Stbi_load causes error from glGetTextureHandleArb()

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, textures, opengl-4

Trying to setup bindless textures, whenever I call `glGetTextureHandleARB()` it results in the OpenGL error `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`. [This page](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_bindless_texture.txt) says this is because my texture object specified is not complete. After spending (too) much time trying to figure out texture completeness [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture#Texture_completeness) (and trying things with `glTexParameters()` to tell OpenGL that I don't have mipmaps), I don't see what I am doing wrong before the call and would appreciate some help.

**texture.c**:

```
#include "texture.h"
#include <glad/glad.h>
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb/stb_image.h>

struct Texture texture_create_bindless_texture(const char *path) {
    struct Texture texture;

    int components;
    void *data = stbi_load(path, &texture.width, &texture.height, &components, 
        4);

    glGenTextures(1, &texture.id);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.id);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texture.width, texture.height,
        0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    texture.bindless_handle = glGetTextureHandleARB(texture.id); 
    glMakeTextureHandleResidentARB(texture.bindless_handle); 

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    stbi_image_free(data);

    return texture;
}
```

**texture.h**:

```
#ifndef TEXTURE_INCLUDED
#define TEXTURE_INCLUDED

#include <glad/glad.h>

struct Texture {
    int width;
    int height;
    GLuint id;
    GLuint64 bindless_handle;
};
struct Texture texture_create_bindless_texture(const char *path);

#endif
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By mistake I gave `stbi_load()` a path that didn't exist, and neglected to add a check if the pointer returned was `NULL` (or if the path existed). I guess somewhere OpenGL didn't like that, but only told me about it when I tried to call `glGetTextureHandleARB()`. At least now I learned my lesson to check stuff passed to me by someone else :)

Comment: "I guess somewhere OpenGL didn't like that, but only told me about it when I tried to call `glGetTextureHandleARB()`." You never _asked_ it (by either calling `glGetError`, or setting up a [debug callback](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output)). It the `stbi_load` fails, the return value is `0`, and the value of `width` and `height` is _undefined_. If you're lucky it contains values which make `glTexImage2D` error out (what happens in your case, just that you never care about the error). If you're unlucky, the values will end up in the valid range, and the `TexImage2D` will crash.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its a completeness issue; Try adding this code:

```cs
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int)TextureWrapMode.ClampToBorderArb);
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)TextureWrapMode.ClampToBorderArb);
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureBorderColor, new float[4]);
```

(This is copied from my C# project, but it should be ez to translate)

---

This might work because bindless textures must have either one of these 4 border colors: (0,0,0,0), (0,0,0,1), (1,1,1,0), or (1,1,1,1) according to [documentation](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_bindless_texture.txt). (I'd love to link the specific paragraph but I can't, so just ctrl+f and search for (0,0,0,0) to find the relevant paragraph)

Comment: I added it, didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Huh. Weird cause I use almost equivalent code and it works. Maybe its worth making sure the data stbi_load returns is what OpenGL expects.
Otherwise I have no idea :/